# Cant fetch current time, date showing year as 1970

Tags: android, datetime, time

```
public static final String inputFormat = "HH:mm";

private Date date;
private Date dateCompareOne;
private Date dateCompareTwo;

LINE 5: 
private String compareStringOne =  String.valueOf(SetTimeActivity.intFromTimeH)+ ":"+ String.valueOf(SetTimeActivity.intFromTimeM) ;

LINE 6:
private String compareStringTwo = String.valueOf(SetTimeActivity.intToTimeH) + ":"+ String.valueOf(SetTimeActivity.intToTimeM);

SimpleDateFormat inputParser = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, Locale.US);
private void compareDates()
{
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

date = parseDate(hour + ":" + minute);
dateCompareOne = parseDate(compareStringOne);
dateCompareTwo = parseDate(compareStringTwo);


        if (!(dateCompareOne.before( date ) && dateCompareTwo.after(date))) {
 ....
```

I am trying to check if current time falls between the specified time. For that I am converting the specified time into strings first (in Line5 & Line6). Even though I get the integer values correct, the string formed always shows "0:0". 
Also, the year is shown as 1970 (The date & the day shown are wrong as well). 
I need to get the current time. What am I doing wrong?

```
    private Date parseDate(String date) {

    try {
        return inputParser.parse(date);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        return new Date(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the date and time are set correct. And to make life easier have a look at the following library. http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ maybe this can help you to make things easier

Answer (score 1):

The parseDate() function returns the time elapsed since the 1st of January 1970. This is known as the Unix Epoch, and it's how all time is represented in Unix computers. By running the parseDate function on a string containing just hours and minutes, you're creating a Date object which represents a time HH:mm past the first of January 1970.

Your code is using a really odd way of getting the current time. Converting a Calendar to two ints, then to a string and finally parsing back to a Date is going to be inefficient and open you up to all sorts of needless errors.

When you initialise a new Date object it is automatically assigned the time of initialisation. Therefore:

```
Date d = new Date();
```

would result in d being the moment of initialisation (that is, this year, month, day, hour, minute, second and microsecond). Then you can just use Date.after() and Date.before().

If you still want to do it via the Calendar method, then you'd be better served by:

```
cal = Calendar.getInstance();    
Date d = cal.getTime();
```

It may be that you've got other issues, but it's worth doing it properly first. When you pass data by writing it as a string (especially when it's time related, with all sorts of ambiguities about what "12" actually represents) you lose all the advantages that language typing gives you.

Comment: I just need to compare the specified time with current time I would prefer it the calendar way. What changes do you suggest in my code?

Comment: The simplest change would be as follows:

Date date = new Date();
dateCompareOne = parseDate(compareStringOne);
dateCompareTwo = parseDate(compareStringTwo);

...

(Apologies for the formatting)

Comment: but I dont get the correct date in compareStringOne & compareStringTwo. Thats my problem to begin with.

Comment: Have you read the [DateUtils.parseDate documentation?](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) It requires a string containing the pattern of the string to parse.

I don't think you're approaching it the right way though. Why are you converting integers representing hours and minutes into a string to then parse back into a Date object? Why not just create a Calender object and set the hours and minutes from the SetTimeActivity? No strings or parsing needed.

Comment: I am having to do that because I get only integers for the specified time (user input).

Answer (score 1):

this code help you

```
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();       
    int  hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
   int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);        if (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
     am_pm = "AM";
        else if (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM) 
            am_pm = "PM"; 

       // Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();   

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());        
        Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already work with `Date` objects why not using the `Date.after(...)` and `Date.before(...)` methods.